# Get the current line in visual mode from a function

Tags: vim

I have a simple vim script that takes a visual block of text and stores it as a list. The problem with the function `VtoList()` is that it executes *after* the cursor returns to the start of the visual block, not before it. Because of this, I have no way of getting the line where the visual block ends.

```
nn <F2> :call VtoList()<CR>

func! VtoList()
    firstline = line('v')  " Gets the line where the visual block begins
    lastline = line('.')   " Gets the current line, but not the one I want.
    mylist = getline(firstline, lastline)
    echo mylist
endfunc
```

The problem is with `line('.')`. It should return the current line of the cursor, but before the function is called, the cursor has already returned to the start of the visual block. Thus, I'm only getting a single line instead of a range of lines.

I put together a solution that sets a mark everytime the user hits <kbd>V</kbd> and sets another mark before the function is called.

```
nnoremap V mV
nnoremap <F2> mZ:call VtoList()<CR>
```

The function works fine if I substitute `line('v')` and `line('.')` with `line("'V")` and `line("'Z")`, but I want to avoid this solution if I can because it could conflict with a user's mappings.

Is there a way I can get current line of a visual block within a function before the cursor has returned to the start of the visual block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `:`, use `<expr>`:

```
function! s:NumSort(a, b)
    return a:a>a:b ? 1 : a:a==a:b ? 0 : -1
endfunction
func! VtoList()
    let [firstline, lastline]=sort([line('v'), line('.')], 's:NumSort')
    let mylist = getline(firstline, lastline)
    echo mylist
    return ""
endfunc
vnoremap <expr> <F2> VtoList()
```

Note other changes: `let` (you forgot it), `sort` (line where selection starts may be after the line where selection ends), `vnoremap` (`line("v")` works only in visual mode), `return` (`expr` mappings return value is executed, but you don't need it, you need only side effects). You can replace the second line with

```
    if mode()=~#"^[vV\<C-v>]"
        let [firstline, lastline]=sort([line('v'), line('.')], 's:NumSort')
    else
        let [firstline, lastline]=sort([line("'<"), line("'>")], 's:NumSort')
    endif
```

The reason why your solution is not working is that when `:` occurs in the mapping, you immediately exit visual mode and enter command mode. `line("v")` works only in visual mode.

Other note: `vnoremap {lhs} :` will produce command line already filled with `'<,'>`. You may have added `range` to the function definition and use `let [firstline, lastline]=sort([a:firstline, a:lastline], 's:NumSort')`. But you nevertheless will exit visual mode with `:`.

Comment: The problem with sort is it sorts alphabetically, so if you range across lines 5-12, it will return [12,5] to [firstline, lastline]. Same problem occurs if you bridge the over the 100s edge, 1000s edge, etc.

Comment: @bobpaul Thanks. I know about this problem now, but I have not yet found all places where sort is used in this way.